# Make whole record read only when picklist value set to "Closed"

Tags: formula, picklist, validation-rule

I have a picklist `picklist1__c` on my opportunity. When the user sets the picklist to `Closed` I want the validation rule to trigger and display an error message "You cannot edit a record that has been set to `Closed`".
This is what I have so far:

```
ISPICKVAL(picklist1__c, "Closed")
```

This makes sense in my eyes. The validation rule triggers, when `picklist1__c` is set to "Closed". However, the validation rule triggers, when I want to set the picklist value to "Closed". Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(picklist1__c), "Closed")
```

you are preventing record to be moved to closed, but you want to prevent it from moving away.